# iCloud numbers reference date/value from another table

Tags: icloud, numbers

I am trying to create a daily budget tracker with separate tables for each month, which I have created.  I now want a front/first table to show:

- the balance as at today's date
- the amount spent today (if any)
- and maybe the balance tomorrow (not too bothered about this one if too difficult).

I would like to say 'if 'January 2016::A1 = TODAY(), January 2016::E1 or if January 2016::A2 = TODAY(), January 2016::E2 and so on looking at each date value across all tables in columns A and when it finds today's date to enter the value in the corresponding E column.

Hopefully this is possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sheet for each month then simply, on the next month in question Edit the balance Bought Forward cell, start with = and then flick back to the previous table and click on the cell with the total for the month. this will then bring that balance forward - repeat the process for all the months and it will show you the projected balances for the year. I use the same type of system, have for many years and it works very well.